# Python in-memory ZipFile not opening

Tags: python, python-3.x

I create an **in-memory ZipFile** object with the following code:

```
def read_test_zip_files():
    file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    data_path = os.path.join(file_path, "test_data")
    
    zip_file_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    zf = ZipFile(zip_file_buffer, "w", ZIP_DEFLATED)

    for root, _, files in os.walk(data_path):
        for file_name in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
            with open(file_path, "r+", encoding='latin-1') as f:
                rel_file_path = str(Path(file_path).relative_to(Path(data_path)))
                zf.writestr(rel_file_path, f.read())

    zf.close()
    zip_file_buffer.seek(0)

    return zf
```

Above function returns a handle to that in-memory object. Now, when I actually try to play around with it, its type comes back as such:

```
<zipfile.ZipFile [closed]>
```

When I try to open it, or access files stored in it, I get the following error:

```
zip_file = read_test_zip_files()

with ZipFile(zip_file, "r") as f:
    # Do something
```

```
AttributeError: 'ZipFile' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean to return `zip_file_buffer`?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: I wanted to attach this in-memory zipfile to a request, and send it to another service. zip_file_buffer is in the end the meat of what I want to dig into in that other service, but first I have to unpack that zip archive.

Comment: @tdelaney: Isn`t it necessary to close an archive, before sending it out to another service?

Comment: @Greem666 - yeah, I think I scanned that code too fast.